# Only one image can't displays image asset - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I want to display an image in my app.
Like this :

```
class _OnBoardingDataPage1State extends State<OnBoardingDataPage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 5.h),
              Text(
                "MugiwarApp",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.h,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/th-2465707242.png",
                height: 250.0,
                width: 250.0,
              )
            ]),
      )),
    ));
  }
}
```

Every images are displaying great, except ONE: my logo.

My pubspec.yaml :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

I can't figure why only my logo can't be displayed.

Comment: Can you try to check the image path and rebuild the app

Comment: Same error after check path and rebuild.

Comment: can I see your images folder in your project root?@Clermoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic issue, three steps to resolve.

1 - define asset correctly

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

2 - stop the application and run  `flutter clean`.

3 - run `flutter pub get`.

now run the app, it will work fine.

Comment: I needed to do this like 4 times but it is working now. But can you explain why all images were working except one ? (my logo was in my `assets/images/`folder since the beginning of my project)

Comment: @Clermoe, you have to specifically define the subdirectories of assets. this is how it works.

Comment: Yes ok, but why all my OTHER images worked (they were in the same folder as my logo), but not my logo ? Maybe just a bug. Anyway thanks you for your help !

Comment: It also depends on when you pasted the new asset to the subdirectory, make sure you run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` whenever you face this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display images from `assets/images` you need to add the full path to pubspec.yaml. The subdirectories are NOT added automatically.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: My previous attempt were with this model. And also didn't work. Also even if I remove the `- assets/images` line, images can be display but not my logo. And that is what I don't understand.

Comment: @Clermoe Do you have an error message?